# Why can't see all task when use 'tasks' task in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, task, depends

```
task startSession << {
chant()
}
def chant() {
ant.echo(message: 'Repeat after me...')
}
3.times {
task "yayGradle$it" << {
println 'Gradle rocks'
}
}
yayGradle0.dependsOn startSession
yayGradle2.dependsOn yayGradle1, yayGradle0
task groupTherapy(dependsOn: yayGradle2)
```

In my script I have startSession task, groupTherapy task and three dynamically generated tasks yayGradle0-3. When I am executing:

```
gradle tasks
```

Part of the output is:

```
Other tasks
-----------
groupTherapy
```

Where are the other tasks? If I execute the command above with parameter `--all` they are visible but not as indipendant tasks but like dependent on **groupTherapy**. Why Gradle doesn't show task startSession as separate task for example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gradle tasks` show tasks that no other task depends on, and tasks that have `task.group` set. The idea is that these are the tasks that are clearly meant to be executed directly, whereas the (often many) remaining tasks aren't. `gradle tasks --all` shows all tasks.