# Why "gradle tasks" doesn't show the tasks?

Tags: gradle

I only have this in my build.gradle file

```
project.task ("Task1")
task("Task2")
task Task3
```

I am using Gradle version 3.5 and when I execute

> gradle tasks

in command line, no tasks are shown.  But when I do

> gradle tasks --all

, then I can see my tasks

```html
Other tasks
-----------
Task1
Task2
Task3
```

Do we need to always use `gradle tasks --all` to see all the tasks?  In some tutorial website, they just use `gradle tasks` and all tasks will be shown. Wondering where do I do wrongly here. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_tasks

Comment: Whoever they are who gave my question -1 , Are you already a Gradle expert since you were born without doing trial & error?  @JBNizet I read that document and didn't understand why we need 'gradle tasks -all'  , meanwhile in the tutorial it can be done with 'gradle tasks'  , thus I ask question. 'gradle -q tasks' doesn't do either.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't need to be an expert to be able to understand *By default, this report shows only those tasks which have been assigned to a task group, so-called visible tasks. You can do this by setting the group property for the task. [example]* If you can't understand that when reading the documentation, I don't see how any answer could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't see all task when use 'tasks' task in Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185321/why-cant-see-all-task-when-use-tasks-task-in-gradle)

Comment: Not to mention that copying and pasting the title of your question in google, and clicking on the **first** link returned by google, links to another similar question which has the answer. No need to be an expert to use google, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, the reason is that according to the documentation the `gradle tasks` command:

> shows only those tasks which have been assigned to a task group, so-called visible tasks. You can do this by setting the group property for the task. You can also set the description property, to provide a description to be included in the report.

You can read about it in the official documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_tasks).

P.S.: in my case, with Grdale 2.14.1, command `gradle tasks` lists all the tasks, even though documentation for this version says the same as for 3.5, that it should lists only grouped tasks by default.

Comment: Thank you. That may explain why in the tutorial he can just do `gradle tasks` and list all the tasks. He used Gradle 2.4. Meanwhile using Gradle 3.5, I can't do that.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Just to clarify: as per my experimentation (Gradle 4.4.1) setting the "description" won't cause your task to be listed... but setting "group" (to any group name, including one you just made up) will...